signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr in Flutter - tflite
I have a flutter code to integrate with tflite. I'm sure that I've added my model in assets.
Future<void> performAudioDetection(List<List<double>> audioData) async {
  InterpreterOptions options = InterpreterOptions();
  options.threads=0;
  final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('models/cry tflite models/cnn_with_trans_model_1.tflite', options: options);
  print(interpreter);
  final batchSize = 1; // Assuming a batch size of 1
  final timeSteps = audioData.length; // Number of time steps (frames)
  final numFeatures = audioData.first.length; // Number of features per frame
  final input = audioData.expand((frame) => frame).toList(); // Flatten the input data

  List<dynamic> inputList = [input];
  var inputTensor = interpreter.getInputTensor(0);
  print('Input shape: ${inputTensor.shape}');

  inputList=inputList.reshape([32,16,8,1]);
  final output = [inputList];// Adjust output shape for binary classification
  print(output.shape);
  // Run inference
  interpreter.runForMultipleInputs(output.cast<Object>(), {0: output}); // Pass input data as a list

  // Extract the output values (assuming two output values)
  final detectionResults = [output[0][0]].map((value) => value[0][0].toDouble()).toList();

  print(detectionResults);
}

Output:
Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
I/flutter (15078): Instance of 'Interpreter'
I/flutter (15078): Input shape: [1, 16, 8, 1]
W/com.example.ap(15078): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/flutter (15078): [1, 32, 16, 8, 1]
W/libc    (15078): Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"
F/libc    (15078): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 15138 (1.ui), pid 15078 (com.example.app)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Redmi/sunny_in/sunny:12/SKQ1.210908.001/V14.0.5.0.SKGINXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-05-05 16:00:34.915786943+0530
Process uptime: 0s
Cmdline: com.example.app
pid: 15078, tid: 15138, name: 1.ui  >>> com.example.app <<<
uid: 10444
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000003b22  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007945334500
    x4  b40000791f051c80  x5  b40000791f051c80  x6  b40000791f051c80  x7  0000000200000004
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  677eec34c4a7b777  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffff80fffffbdf
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000200000004  x14 0000000000000080  x15 0000000000000004
    x16 0000007a65b26d30  x17 0000007a65b00870  x18 0000007944f68000  x19 0000000000003ae6
    x20 0000000000003b22  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007945336000  x23 00000079453348f8
    x24 0000007945336000  x25 b40000792d927100  x26 0000000000000098  x27 0000000000000070
    x28 0000000000004b40  x29 0000007945334580
    lr  0000007a65ab0c1c  sp  00000079453344e0  pc  0000007a65ab0c48  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000008bc48  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: e1f31041be009cf8613d6678cdccd160)
      #01 pc 000000000011dc60  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #02 pc 00000000001d9b8c  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #03 pc 00000000001debf8  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #04 pc 00000000001d9498  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #05 pc 00000000002f81b8  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #06 pc 00000000002f7ba0  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #07 pc 00000000002e5584  /data/app/~~8fOZw8yJdQcMSjchfOYTOA==/com.example.app-7i4nH-RT5c2FHkSDj1ZcrQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so
      #08 pc 0000000000007bc4  [anon:dart-code]
Lost connection to device.

My Build.gradle in app:
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.4.0"
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc2'
    implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }
    implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }
}

android {
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}

My app crashes when tflite model runs. I tried executing this code in multiple devices. I ran on physical device rather than emulator. Still the same crash persists
I tried solutions of various SO questions and Git issues. But nothing worked for me.

I think you missed the 'await'
use await interpreter.runForMultipleInputs(output.cast<Object>(), {0: output});

This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Did you try changing the 'options.threads=0;' to something like 'options.threads=4;' ? It needs some CPU threads to run I guess.

Still my app crashes
